# How to persist Azure_AD id_token in session user Claims

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I want to store my Azure Ad authenticated Id_token in user claims and browser cookies. how can I achieve this.
This is my start up file.

```
 services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddAzureAd(options =>
            {
                Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                AzureAdOptions.Settings = options;
            })
            .AddCookie(cfg => cfg.SlidingExpiration = true);
            services.AddSession();
        }


        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseSession(); 
            app.UseAuthentication();
}
```

Azure Ad Authentication builder class is below

````
 public static class AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAd(this AuthenticationBuilder builder)
            => builder.AddAzureAd(_ => { });

        public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAd(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<AzureAdOptions> configureOptions)
        {
            builder.Services.Configure(configureOptions);
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>, ConfigureAzureOptions>();
            builder.AddOpenIdConnect();
            return builder;
        }

        private class ConfigureAzureOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>
        {
            private readonly AzureAdOptions _azureOptions;

            public ConfigureAzureOptions(IOptions<AzureAdOptions> azureOptions)
            {
                _azureOptions = azureOptions.Value;
            }
            public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
            {
                options.ClientId = _azureOptions.ClientId;
                options.Authority = _azureOptions.Authority;
                options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
                options.CallbackPath = _azureOptions.CallbackPath;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ClientSecret = _azureOptions.ClientSecret;
                options.Resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com"; // AAD graph

                // Without overriding the response type (which by default is id_token), the OnAuthorizationCodeReceived event is not called.
                // but instead OnTokenValidated event is called. Here we request both so that OnTokenValidated is called first which 
                // ensures that context.Principal has a non-null value when OnAuthorizeationCodeReceived is called
                options.ResponseType = "id_token code";

                // Subscribing to the OIDC events
                options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived;
                options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed;
            }

            public void Configure(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
            {
                Configure(Options.DefaultName, options);
            }

           ```
            private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context)
            {
                // Acquire a Token for the Graph API and cache it using ADAL. In the TodoListController, we'll use the cache to acquire a token for the Todo List API
                string userObjectId = (context.Principal.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"))?.Value;
                var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(context.Options.Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectId, context.HttpContext.Session));
                var credential = new ClientCredential(context.Options.ClientId, context.Options.ClientSecret);

                var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(context.TokenEndpointRequest.Code,
                    new Uri(context.TokenEndpointRequest.RedirectUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), credential, context.Options.Resource);

                // Notify the OIDC middleware that we already took care of code redemption.
                context.HandleCodeRedemption(authResult.AccessToken, context.ProtocolMessage.IdToken);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// this method is invoked if exceptions are thrown during request processing
            /// </summary>
            private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedContext context)
            {
                context.HandleResponse();
                context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
````